# Model-First Entity Framework: using Enums or default values for Entity using Designer (.NET 4.0)

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have started learning Entity Framework recently and not sure what to search for this task.

I have an Entity called `EstimatedEffort` with property `Status` which can be `Active, Inactive, TBD`. Now using my previous experience with C#, I might have created an Enum for status with three values and kept `Status` field of integer type in `EstimatedEffort` database table. How I can achieve the same using Entity Framework Designer?

My first approach: I found that you can't use enums in Entity Framework, so I decided to create a separate entity for `Status` which means I am keeping a separate table for `Status` in Database. But how I add  `Active, Inactive, TBD` values to it using designer?

I read that we can create and use our `Insert, Update, Delete` stored procedure and I might create an insert stored procedure to add default values. But before pursuing further on this approach, I thought to consider asking whether I'm going on right track or I'm missing something. Thanks

**Enum type not available in property types**

[image]

Comment: You can use byte- or int-based enums in Entity Framework; in Code First it'll map them to numeric fields (and back again) and in Database First you can specify the enum as the type of that property from the properties pane for that property in the model browser.

Comment: @anaximander I tried looking for Enum type in property but there is not any. I'm using visual studio 2010 and I somewhere read that enum type were added in .NET 4.5 (which is not supported by VS 2010). I'm currently using .NET 4.0. Any work around for this?

Comment: There may be; I don't know of one myself though. Did you create your enums in the model designer?

Comment: I am not creating Enum (as I could not find a way to do so). I am creating entities in designer

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/08/12/enums-in-the-entity-designer.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: Thanks @anaximander for the effort. But I read on this page only that this post is out-dated and for using enum, pre-requisite is VS 2012 :(... Do you know anyway of adding default values to an Entity using Designer?

Comment: Enums are not supported when you are using any version but EF6 on .NET Framework 4. We shipped EF6 Beta1 that includes tooling but for technical reasons EF6 on .NET Framework 4 is not supported in Beta. In addition the tooling we are shipping will not work with VS2010. So in any case you need to move to VS2012. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I felt like I need to go through the basics of Entity Framework so starting reading Programming ENtity Framework by Julia. Do you know any other resource which might be helpful? I need a quick headstart on building ASP.NET MVC4 using EF (with Oracle db)

Answer (score 0):

1. create a property with int value in your entity(that I call it status)
2. in model designer set it setter and getter private
3. create a partial class in your model namespace with same name of your entity name
4. create a public Enumeration property in partial class(that I call it situation)
5. in situation getter return your private property(status)
6. in situation setter set value of private property(status)